# Ignored cmd timeout in awaited call

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, process, cmd, async-await

I have the following code:

```
Try
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("CMD.EXE")
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " & commandToRun ' run command then quit
Using proc As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)

    Dim stdOutput As Task(Of String)
    Dim stdError As Task(Of String)
    Using stdOutputStreamReader As StreamReader = proc.StandardOutput
        stdOutput = stdOutputStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()

        Using stdErrorStreamReader As StreamReader = proc.StandardError
            stdError = stdErrorStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()

            Dim stdOutputString As String = Await stdOutput
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stdOutputString) Then
                Return New Tuple(Of String, Boolean)(Await stdError, False)
            Else
                Return New Tuple(Of String, Boolean)(stdOutputString, True)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
' Catch error...
```

Where the command to run is:

```
commandToRun As String = "timeout 15 > nul & forfiles /S /M *.* /P C:\logs /c ""cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime @path"""
```

My question is, why is it that when I get to the `Await stdOutput` (in much less than fifteen seconds), the result of the second part of the command is already there and waiting for me? It's like it's ignoring the `timeout`.

Edit

Using `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 15 > nul` instead of the `timeout` works... but I'd like to know why the `timeout` is ignored, or how to resolve it without using a hack.

Using the `/nobreak` flag also doesn't seem to do it.

Edit 2 - calling methods:

In a backgroundworker's DoWork() method:

```
PollAndUpdateLogFiles()
```

Which calls

```
Friend Async Sub PollAndUpdateLogFiles()
    Dim response As String = Await GetLogDataManually()
    ... ' parse to XML, then to an object that is bound by a DataGrid
End Sub
```

Which calls

```
Protected Async Function GetLogDataManually() As Task(Of String)
    Dim commandToRun As String = "timeout 15 > nul & forfiles /S /M *.* /P C:\logs /c ""cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime @path"""
    Dim response As Tuple(Of String, Boolean) = Await HelperMethods.CallCommandAndGetResponse(commandToRun)
    If response.Item2 Then
        Return response.Item1
    ... ' else error
End Function
```

Which calls the code at the top of the question (that's the entire method)

Comment: Can you post the complete method and the calling code?

Comment: done. The method I provided intially is the entire method, with the exception of a try-catch that throws an exception (but doesn't get called in this case, so is irrelevant)

Comment: `PollAndUpdateLogFiles` will return to its caller before the task returned by `GetLogDataManually` ends. Could that be the problem?

Comment: yes, that's intentional - but why would it then ignore the timeout and jump straight to the second part of the command?

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this?